# Fetching data from json and destructuring returns undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I was trying to make a small project that displays movies using fetch API from OMDB api. But while destructuring values i'm only getting undefined upon using console.log(). Looked into documentation and applied various method but still can't figure it out.

```
let movies =
{
    api_key: '######',

    fetch_movies : async function(title){
        let receive = await fetch('https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=######'+ '&t='+title); 
        let data = await receive.json();
        console.log(data);
        this.displayMovies(data);
    },

    displayMovies : function(data){
        const{Title, Plot, Director} = data;
        console.log(Title, Plot, Director);
    }
};
```

The JSON file is something like:

```
{
Title: "......",
Year: ".....",
Rated: "....",
Released: ".......",
Runtime: "......",
Genre: ".....",
Director: ".....",
Writer: ".......",
```

Comment: What does `console.log(data)` show?

Comment: The json data that is fetched

Comment: If the destructuring of the data isn't throwing an error I guess you are passing an object indeed. Have you tried checking what data you receive in displayMovies? Maybe there's another layer wrapping around the actual data. So just do `console.log(data)` inside displayMovies

Comment: well , It's working for me .  calling ``movies.fetch_movies("Hello");`` returns me an Object  ``{Title: 'Hello', Year: '2008', Rated: 'N/A', Released: '10 Oct 2008', Runtime: '129 min', …}`` and ``Hello Call-center workers receive a phone call from God. Atul Agnihotri``

Comment: So, i just tried console.log(data) inside displayMovies and when i called the function in console, movies.displayMovies('Name_of_the_movie") it only returns the title of the movie which in this case is Name_of_the_movie

Comment: So, movies.displayMovies("Hello") worked too @Pariket-ck?

Comment: That's not how you're meant to use displayMovies though, is it? You should call movies.fetch_movies('Blade Runner') and then see what displayMovies receives.

Comment: Oh ok gotcha.. So, on doing so yeah i received the complete data @shidoro

Comment: What is the movie title you are searching?

Comment: Goodfellas @SabirAmeen

Comment: I think something is missing while destructuring but can't figure out what

Comment: @SabirAmeen it doesn't matter. The OP was misusing the functions, by directly calling `displayMovies` and expecting to see the result of the fetch. The question should be closed as there is no problem to solve.

Comment: According to your previous reply "*So, on doing so yeah i received the complete data @shidoro*" you are receiving the data. If destructuring returns undefined that means that either you are mispelling the keys or that the keys are somewhat in a deeper level, or that the data is an array and you are trying to extract keys from an array.